# jquery-mobile css breaks on page load

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a master page with buttons, on clicking a button a different page(jsp) is loaded into the contents div of the  master page.The master page has all the required jquery mobile css/js files included. But when click happend the child page is displayed with out any j-m css in it.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable those widgets in your code. so if you append a $('') to the page you need to call $('a').button() on it to give it the jqm classes and functions.

remember to do this after you append it.